# How do I add missing rows AND interpolated value to a data frame in R?

Tags: r, interpolation

I have a table of data like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(
   age  = c(0,10,20,40,70,100),
   surv = c(1.0,0.9,0.8,0.6,0.3,0.0)
)
```

I would like to add a row for every age that is missing (30,50,60,80,90) and then I would like to add the linear interpolation for surv to the new row. So the new rows would be (30,0.7) (80, 0.2) etc.

This is just an example. I am actually working with a much larger dataset that goes from 0 to 5,000,000 by 10 (with lots of missing rows) so I need some automation.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Learn to use `dput` to present an unambiguous version of an R object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a master dataset then use `approx` to linearly interpolate:

```
newdat <- merge(data.frame(age=seq(0,100,10)),dat,all=TRUE)
newdat$surv[is.na(newdat$surv)] <- 
    with(newdat, approx(age, surv, xout=age)$y)[is.na(newdat$surv)]

newdat

#   age surv
#1    0  1.0
#2   10  0.9
#3   20  0.8
#4   30  0.7
#5   40  0.6
#6   50  0.5
#7   60  0.4
#8   70  0.3
#9   80  0.2
#10  90  0.1
#11 100  0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and "dirty" method to add rows. While this does not insert the ages in order, you can do the ordering later and the substitution of the values for the previously missing rows.

Code Below:

```
 df <- data.frame(age=c(0,10,20,40,70,100), surv=c(1.0,0.9,0.8,0.6,0.3,0.0))
 addrow <- c(30,50,60,80,90)

 df_save <- df
 i = 1

 for (r in c(1:nrow(df) ))  {

     if (addrow[i] %in% df[,1] ) {
        print(paste("TRUE", , sep=":"))
     } else {
       if (i <= length(addrow) ) {
          newrow <- c(addrow[i], 999)
          df <- rbind(df[1:r,], newrow, df[(r+1):nrow(df),])
       }
     }
     i = i+1
 }

df[order[df$age],)
```

Then substitute the 999 values for the respective age's surv value.

This is to give you an idea on how to automate the row binding.